# How to create a NET 6 plugin that enables a dashboard route to my API

Tags: user-interface, razor, plugins, .net-6.0

I'm building a nuget package for net 6 APIs.
That package is a "plugin" who must enable a dashboard. The dashboard is basically a form and a list of the form result (angular or razor/blazor, whatever).

Projects like Hangfire or Xabaril (Healthcheck) uses this feature.

It's important to **don't create any dependency** (like node, for angular) for who uses the plugin.

How can i make this?

I tried to create a Razor project and make the API refers to this project, but injecting the dependencies of the Razor with a extension, then, refering in the API Program.cs.

I came really close with this approach, but the API doesn't recognize the css/js files (I configured the static files, but I don't know if it was right), although the navigation was ok. A error "negotiate" appears in the browser console too.